# is there any way to merge more than one flutter app into single app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a student and very new in flutter app development and still trying to learn flutter. If I have more than one flutter application (As Backend in php, mysqli) and I want to merge in a single application so what I need to do, I researched so much on google but I didn't get any better solution, I want know:

1. is it possible?
2. is it very difficult?
3. what is the requirement?

Comment: What do you mean by "merging apps"? you need to elaborate.

Comment: "merging apps" mean i want to create a one new app and in this app i want to add all other apps

Comment: Well then sure, it's possible. Level of difficulty depends on your code architecture and the scale of the apps, and the requirement is to know what you are doing.

Comment: To be more concrete, you will have to go through the old apps code and add everything in the new app by hand. There is no way to just say 'merge' and have both apps in a new app.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. You can do it as long as the resources don't conflict.

Everything is a widget in Flutter. An app itself is also a widget. You can take your whole app and put it inside of another widget. The problem is dependencies. Widgets are just lightweight representations of render objects, they declare how the UI looks (size, layout, hittest etc.). The data that populates them comes from business logic. So the answer depends on the business logic of the apps. It is possible if they don't conflict.

For example if there are two apps that creates a TCP socket with the same port, they will conflict. Another example can be Firebase. An app can not be integrated with multiple Firebase projects.

A working example could be multiple RESTful apps. Two apps that makes HTTP request to get data from the backend will not conflict. They will make seperate requests and have seperate states. It is just like having two pages that fetches different data from the backend.